# Prepared statements doesn't return results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I trying to do all my querys with prepared statements but is new for me and I have some troubles. This is first query and doesn't echo result from table. This is what I've done so far. May be is realy newbie question but is something completely new for me.

```
if(isset($_GET['joke_id'])){
            $joke_id = $_GET['joke_id'];

            $qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM joke WHERE joke_cat = ?");
            $qry->bind_param('i', $joke_id);
            $qry->execute();
            $result = $qry->get_result();
            $result->fetch_array();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));*/
            $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);

            if (!$line) echo '';
            $previd = -1;
            $currid = $line[0];
            if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                $previous_ids = array();
                do {
                    $previous_ids[] = $line[0];
                    $currid = $line[0];
                    if ($currid == $_GET['id']) break;
                    $previd = end($previous_ids);
                    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
                } while ($line);
            }
   if ($line) {
                echo "<div id=\"box\">";
                echo nl2br($line['text']) . "<br /><br />";
                echo "<div id=\"share\"><span class='st_facebook' displayText='Facebook'></span>
                <span class='st_twitter' displayText='Tweet'></span>
                <span class='st_googleplus' displayText='Google +'></span></div>";
                echo '<br /><br /><br />';
                echo "</div>";

            }
            else echo '<p>Empty category</p><br/>';
```

This is what I use right now before to try PDO and it's work with no problems.

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM joke WHERE joke_cat = '$joke_id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));
```

Comment: Please don't use mixed style of mysqli, which make eye hurt.

Comment: Why you are using `mysqli_query` and PDO at the same time?

Comment: So where do you output the results?

Comment: `$result->fetch_array()` is supposed to do what? then you immediately overwrite the value of `$result` with a new query.... so lose whatever is there

Comment: I added where I echo results. As I said is something new for me and I don't know realy how to rewrite all in PDO.

Comment: Ok @MarkBaker thats make sense..

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET['joke_id']` and `$_GET['joke_cat']` is set ?

or try

```
$qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM joke WHERE joke_cat =:joke_cat");
$qry->bindParam(':joke_cat', $_GET['joke_cat'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$qry->execute();
$result = $qry->fetchAll();
```

Comment: This should be a comment.